# Take off .txt on a string?

Tags: android

My app has a ListActivity where it shows all the .txt files in a certain directory. 
Here is the code that gets the File names:

```
 List<String> textFiles(String directory) {
        List<String> textFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File dir = new File(directory);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                textFiles.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        return textFiles;
    }
```

Problem is all of the file names returned have .txt at the end. How can I make it so that ending is cut off? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to imagine that you wrote the snippet posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `String.replace` method

For example

```
String newName = file.getName().replace(".txt","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be just a simple [String Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
textFiles.add(file.getName().split(".txt")[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, but what if there are other periods in the string?